# What is the common term for both class and object?

Tags: class, oop, object, naming

All OOP languages support having a variable refer to an object. But some languages also support having a variable refer to a class (class-reference type). Say I have a method that will accept either an object or a class as its parameter. What would I call the parameter? In other words, is there a term that both encapsulates "object" and "class"?

To further clarify, here's some (otherwise useless) PHP code that illustrates what I mean by class reference vs object reference:

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public function shout(string $message) {
        echo strtoupper("$message\n");
    }
}

class Bar {
    public function shout(string $message) {
        echo "!!! $message !!!\n";
    }
}

/**
 * @param mixed $classOrObject
 */
function shoutOut($classOrObject) {

    if (is_object($classOrObject)) {
        $classOrObject->shout('I got an object');
    } elseif (is_string($classOrObject)) {
        $object = new $classOrObject();
        $object->shout('I got a class');
    }

}

shoutOut(new Foo());
shoutOut(Bar::class);
```

A rephrase of the question can hence be

> What is a better name for the $classOrObject parameter?

As a third attempt at homing in on what I'm really after here, imagine you're writing an introduction to OOP. You could say something like

> The main ingredients of the OOP paradigm are the class and object.

So if we were to substitute "main ingredients" with a more theoretically accurate term, my question is what would that term be? If classes were apples and objects were pears, we'd call them both "fruit". But classes and objects are not fruit, so what do we call them?

Comment: Terminology is largely language dependent. Please specify a language.

Comment: A class is a type and an object is a variable. The only situation I can think of where these two notions can be interchanged is with property values defined at class level. Class then acts as a global variable. Not all languages allow that.

Comment: @sweeper: Any language. I'm desperate! ;-)

Comment: After your edit, I would say that the paradigm is called dynamic typing, the parameter is called parameter or argument or variable, and it can hold values of any type, including values of type class or type. Therefore the common name would be: value

Comment: Your analogy doesn't work. Classes and objects are not like apples and pears. They are like fruits and apples.

Comment: @mouviciel: Most certainly not. An object is not a subtype of a class, it's an instance of it, which is very different. It would be like saying that a house is a subtype of its blueprint.

Answer (score -1):

An object is instance of class. 
A class is like mold and the object is an element created with this mold.

Comment: You might want to re-read the question. I didn't ask about the difference between a class and an object. I ask if these two "building blocks" have a common term. Like "building block" :-)